# Lead Assignment Rules

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lead, salesforce-communities, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am newbie in Salesforce and my company is switching our CRM to Salesforce. So currently we are learning and doing gap analysis. Previously we had 50+ active lead assignment rules each contains various queries but in salesforce we can have only one rule active at a time. Any suggestion how can I implement this without using process builder & workflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate your 50+ lead assignment rules from your previous CRM as 50+ entries under one lead assignment rule in Salesforce.

In Salesforce a lead assignment rule can have multiple entries for routing the lead. Each entry is composed from one or more criteria. You can think of each entry as a business rule in a traditional sense. The overall lead assignment rule is a collection of these business rules.

Take a look at [Convert and Assign Leads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/admin_intro_opptys_leads/admin_intro_opptys_leads_leads) Trailhead tutorial for an example.

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, I also looked for that . Btw do you have any idea how many maximum rule entries can we define under one rule ? @identigral

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rules_limits.htm&type=5